# how add new data to array json with php?

Tags: php, jquery, json, file

I have 4 input, which sent by Ajax 4 data, to a php file:
how can I load json file and then add new data whih php?

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="surname">
<input type="text" id="mobile">
<input type="text" id="email">
<script>
var name = $("#name").val();
var surname = $("#surname").val();
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
$.ajax({type:"POST",
url:"fill.php",
data:"name="+nombre+"&surname="+surname+"&mobile="+mobile+"&email="+email,
success:function(data) {
```

}
});
JSON file: (people.json)

```
{
"1":
{
    "Name" : "Jhon",
    "Surname" : "Kenneth",
    "mobile" : 329129293,
    "email" : "jhon@gmail.com"
},
"2":
{
    "Name" : "Thor",
    "Surname" : "zvalk",
    "mobile" : 349229293,
    "email" : "thor@gmail.com"
}
}
```

here I have a mistake fill.php file :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname =$_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$file = 'people.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$newdata = array('name'=>$name, 'surname' => $surname, 'mobile'=>$mobile,'email'=>$email);
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
?>
```

when I exeute it, it delete all the people.json date, and everytime that I add new data, it give me the next result: [{},{},{},{}]

Comment: the first time, when you exceute it, it works ok??

Comment: you have had several posts about this json file. Why not change the data structure in the file so that it matches what you need in page and don't have to map the data in browser to another format. Then you will be working with same structure in both javascript and php

Comment: yeah, but then when I fill the form, it delete all the people.json data

Comment: try `json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);` this should return an array no matter what.

Comment: if file was just an array php code would work. And you are having to convert the object to array in javascript

Comment: @dualed yeah, you right it works ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a secnod parameter to json_decode so it becomes an array, try this

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname =$_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$file = 'people.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);
$newdata = array('name'=>$name, 'surname' => $surname, 'mobile'=>$mobile,'email'=>$email);
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
?>
```

Comment: what's the difference between json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true) and son_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);, is the same?

Comment: @Kakitori 1 and true do the same thing, same as 0 and false do are the same :)

Comment: @Kakitori as a side note, your JSON array should start on 0 not on 1 :) just a suggestion

Comment: what you mean?? i have to change json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1) by json_decode(file_get_contents($file),0)??

Answer (score 0):

json decode accepts a second parameter, set it and you get arrays not stdClass objects.